# Windows server 2008 DNS http redirect

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, redirect

on my lan i have two servers. One windows server 2008 and one debian webserver. I would like to configure my windows DNS to redirect all traffic on my lan to, for example "example.com" to my local webserver (on 192.168.10.24). How do i configure my windows DNS to do this kind of redirection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to do a URL redirect or just point example.com to 192.168.10.24?

if it's the latter, just create a zone called example.com with an A record of 192.168.10.24.

If you're trying to do *.example.com to example.com then you still will want an A record as above, but you would create a cname called *.example.com to point to example.com.

Then simply make sure your clients have your local DNS server pushed out (via DHCP).

If i misunderstood the request, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a secondary zone on your windows serveur 2008 DNS role, which will act as a redirection to your Debian server that contains the primary zone file.

To do so, just go in your DNS Role, left click on left listing, and select "New zone", it will ask you to choose between a principal, secondary, or stub zone. Select secondary, then all you have to do is to give the assistant the IP address of your debian server.

If the zone you want to redirect is well configured( use check zone-names -z if not), it will import the zone file from Debian and create the secondary zone on the windows server.

I don't know if that solve your problem, btw i don't know a way to do so automatically, nor dynamically .